# What is [External Frame] on Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, memory-leaks, diagnostic-tools

**Prerequisites**

- C++ project
- Build by Cmake on windows x64 debug mode on
- using external library (.lib)
- pdb included

**Flow**

- take a breakpoint
- on Diagnostic Tools, memory usage, turn on Heap profiling
- 1st loop I take snapshot
- 2nd loop I take snapshot again, and still on 2nd row, I click the on Native Heap Size(diff)
- click Stact tab
- Identify the diff size in bytes

**Question**

I try to find memory leak on my project by running builtin VS Performance Profiler tools.
After I did flow above, I spot on Identifier column,
there is a function name that I don't know where it come from, its called [External Frame].
Can somebody explain to me what is that?

[image: diagnostic-tools]

Thank you